# Application of Hensel's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, valuation-theory

Show that the polynomial $\Phi(x)=x^2 -2 \in O(\widehat{\Bbb Q_2})[x] $ has no root in $\widehat{\Bbb Q_2}$, even though $\bar\Phi(x)\in E(\widehat{\Bbb Q_2})[x]$ has a root in $E(\widehat{\Bbb Q_2}) $. Reconcile this observation with Hensel's lemma. Here $\widehat{\Bbb Q_2}$ is the completion of $\Bbb Q$ in the $V_2$-topology, $E(\widehat{\Bbb Q_2}) $ is the notation for residue class field and $O(\widehat{\Bbb Q_2})=\{x\in\widehat{\Bbb Q_2}\mid V(x)\leq1\}.$  (*Associative Algebras* by Richard S. Pierce, section 17.4, page 325, Exercise 3)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I have the book yet I cannot find in it what the notations $\;O...\;,\;\;E...\;$ mean. The notation $\;\widehat{\Bbb Q_2}\;$ I suppose means the completion of the $\;2-$adics.

Comment: In context, surely $O$ means "integers of" and "E" means "residue field" of, so it means $\mathbf Z_2$ and ${\mathbf F}_2$ respectively, in more standard notation.

Comment: Hensel's lemma in its basic form is about lifting *simple* roots mod $p$ to roots in the $p$-adics. The mod 2 reduction has a double root, so the basic version of Hensel's lemma does not apply and tell you anything about this situation.

Comment: Highly unconventional notation. But whatever version of Hensel you use, its hypotheses are not satisfied here. The polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein, of course.

Comment: Associative algebra by Richard S. Pierce page 324